# Celery event args capturing

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I want to capture task arguments using the task events provided by celery.
I'm using redis as the backend and broker (Pickle as the serializer). According to the documentation, it's possible to get this info by listening to `task-received` handler, where args will be populated.

The problem I'm facing is, for small data input this works as expected. When I use a large input (binary file - ~16MB), args received by events is much smaller and truncated.

Does anybody know the reason for this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery has a limit on the size of the data pushed to an event.

It is configurable using [repr_maxsize](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.resultrepr_maxsize).

I'm guessing, but this probably has significant performance penalties and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! Will it be possible to get it from redis?
I've checked 'AsyncResult` but args are not there.